# How do I $watch the Angular-ui's new ui-select (former ui-select2) search string changes?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui, ui-select2

I noticed that the Angular-UI have discontinued their UI-Select2 directive in favor of the new UI-Select (with multiple themes - select2, bootstrap, selectize).

It looks like this:

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="multipleDemo.colors" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select colors...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="color in availableColors | filter:$select.search">
        {{color}}
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>

<p>Selected: {{multipleDemo.colors}}</p>
```

Initially my selectbox is supposed to be empty but ready to take typed characters, that is a string of at least 4 characters and then make an API call to retrieve a list of suggested values which are to populate the box. One value will then be chosen, and searching should be repeated as needed.

First I tried `$watch`ing the `ng-model` which in this case is `multipleDemo.colors` (using this example from the demos). The API call never occurred and then I realized why. The actual model is not changed at all because it only changes when a selection is made (my selectbox is empty so nothing can be selected).

My conclusion is that I should (be able to) `$watch` what's been added as filter, namely `filter: $select.search`.

Does anyone know how am I supposed to use that one in my controller?

This:

```
$scope.$watch('$select.search', function(newVal){
    alert(newVal);
});
```

doesn't work.

EDIT:
For anyone's reference, see this short discussion: [Is it possible to add support for custom query function like the select2?](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/30)

EDIT 2:

I solved this by using `$emit` from within the directive so the value is available in my controller now. But now I'd like to know how can I override this part of the directive so the directive itself can be left intact so it doesn't break in future updates?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by creating an event in the right spot within the directive and then `$emitting` it - eventually I am able to listen to the event in my controller and use the value.

The downside to this is that I've put this directly in the 3rd-party's directive so it can't be safely updated. I need to find a way to override the directive. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Next time you run "bower update ui-select" come here and unmark this as the answer. btw, have you checked Chris Bond answer?

Answer (score 16):

Use the `refresh` attribute on the `<ui-select-choices>` element to call a function on your scope with `$select.search` as the parameter:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="color in multipleDemo.availableColors | filter:$select.search"
                   refresh="refreshColors($select.search)"
                   refresh-delay="0">
    {{color}}
</ui-select-choices>
```

Then use the function (`refreshColors()` in this snippet) to update `multipleDemo.availableColors` accordingly.

You may also use the `refresh-delay` attribute to specify how many milliseconds to *debounce* the function so it is not called too many times in quick succession.

I have also put `availableColors` on `multipleDemo` like you have done for `multipleDemo.colors`, as is [recommended](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/FAQs).

Reference: [ui-select directive wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select#examples-async) under section **Examples: Async**.

Comment: It works as long as you don't need it inside ng-repeat.

Comment: Are you repeating the `<ui-select>`? In that case you could pass a second parameter to `refresh` function to identify the instance.

Comment: mmmm yes...but does that feels alright? see https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/279#issuecomment-67360055

Comment: I assume you have something like `<div ng-repeat="item in list"><ui-select>...</ui-select></div>`... to make the `refresh` function aware of the context, pass it in like `refresh="refreshColors(item, $select.search)"`. Then you can access all useful properties of each `item` (like IDs) to do whatever differentiation you need.

Comment: Added this then used a function.  Worked well for me.  <ui-select-choices refresh='refresh($select)' refresh-delay='0' ... >

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be an `on-select` attribute, see [Github example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-event-on-select.html):

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" on-select="someFunction($item, $model)" [...]>
  [...]
</ui-select>
```

Comment: I believe this is executed after an option is selected. What I needed was to trigger an action when character (or a threshold thereof is reached) are input.

Answer (score 1):

Use ngInit to get the value,

```
<div ui-select ng-init="mySelect = $select"></div>
<button ng-click="search(mySelect.search)">Search</button>
```

You can alse watch 'mySelect' instead

```
$scope.$watch('mySelect.search', function(newVal){
    alert(newVal);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Bear with me, this is my first answer on SO.

So the current top answer does not work for me. Just want to provide another option. The refresh property on the ui-select-choices does not trigger the named function in my scope.

I followed the info [in their docs](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/Accessing-%24select) for accessing the UI select for custom features. Create a custom directive in which you watch `$select.search` like

```js
myModule.directive('myUiSelect', function() {
  return {
    require: 'uiSelect',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, $select) {
      scope.$watch('$select.search', function (search) {
        if (search) {
          ...
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

and then include the directive on your `<ui-select my-ui-select>` tag.